# keeping the row number in a data frame column

Tags: r, list, dataframe, row-number

I have a bunch of .txt files (articles) in a folder, I use a for cycle in order to get text from all of them on R

```
input_loc <- "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Folder"
files <- dir(input_loc, full.names = TRUE)
text <- c()
for (f in files) {
  text <- c(text, paste(readLines(f), collapse = "\n"))
}
```

from here, I tokenize per paragraphs and I get each paragraph in each article:

```
paragraphs <- tokenize_paragraphs(text)
sapply(paragraphs, length)
paragraphs
```

then I unlist and transform into a dataframe

```
par_unlisted<-unlist(paragraphs)
par_unlisted
par_unlisted_df<-as.data.frame(par_unlisted)
```

BUT doing that I no longer have an inter-article separation of paragraph numbers (e.g. first article has 6 paragraphs, before unlisting the first paragraph of the second article would still have a [1] in front, while after unlisting it will have a [7]).
What I would like to do is, once I have the dataframe, having a column with the number of the paragraph, then create another column named "article" with the number of the article.
Thank You in advance

EDIT
this is roughly what I get once I get to `paragraphs`:

```
> paragraphs
[[1]]
[1] "The Miami Dolphins have decided to use their non-exclusive franchise 
tag on wide receiver Jarvis Landry."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

[2] "The Dolphins tweeted the announcement Tuesday, the first day teams 
could use their franchise or transition tags. The salary for wide receivers 
getting the franchise tag this offseason is expected to be around $16.2 
million, which will be quite the raise for Landry, who made $894,000 last 
season."    
[[2]]
[1] "Despite months of little-to-no movement on contract negotiations, 
Jarvis Landry has often stated his desire to stay in Miami."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

[2] "The Dolphins used their lone tool to wipe away negotation-driven stress 
-- at least in the immediate future -- and ensure Landry won't be lured away 
from Miami, placing the franchise tag on the receiver on Tuesday, the team 
announced."
```

I would want to keep the paragraph number (`[n]`) as a column in the dataframe, because when I unlist them they no longer stay separated per article and then per paragraph, but I get them in sequence, let's say (basically in the example I've just posted I no longer have

```
[[1]]
[1] ...
[2] ...

[[2]]
[1] ...
[2] ...
```

but I get

```
[1] ...
[2] ...
[3] ...
[4] ...
```

Comment: Could you show us some mock data? Right now it is hard to imagine the structure of your objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider iterating through the *paragraphs* list and build a list of dataframes with needed article and paragraph numbers with a final row bind through all dataframe elements.

**Input** Data

```
paragraphs <- list(
     c("The Miami Dolphins have decided to use their non-exclusive franchise tag on wide receiver Jarvis Landry.",   
        "The Dolphins tweeted the announcement Tuesday, the first day teams could use their franchise or transition tags. The salary for wide receivers 
getting the franchise tag this offseason is expected to be around $16.2 million, which will be quite the raise for Landry, who made $894,000 last 
season."),
     c("Despite months of little-to-no movement on contract negotiations, Jarvis Landry has often stated his desire to stay in Miami.",
      "The Dolphins used their lone tool to wipe away negotation-driven stress -- at least in the immediate future -- and ensure Landry won't be lured away 
from Miami, placing the franchise tag on the receiver on Tuesday, the team announced."))
```

Dataframe Build

```
df_list <- lapply(seq_along(paragraphs), function(i)

  setNames(data.frame(i, 1:length(paragraphs[[i]]), paragraphs[[i]]), 
           c("article_num", "paragraph_num", "paragraph"))      
)

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

**Output** Result

```
final_df

#   article_num paragraph_num                                             paragraph
# 1           1             1 The Miami Dolphins have decided to use their non-e...
# 2           1             2 The Dolphins tweeted the announcement Tuesday, the...
# 3           2             1 Despite months of little-to-no movement on contrac...
# 4           2             2 The Dolphins used their lone tool to wipe away neg...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just one more question: is there a way to avoid basically copypasting the text into the various c()? Because articles are way longer than this and they are much more than just two, I just took a sample from what I'm working with

Comment: The input data here is only to replicate your *paragraphs* object. There is no need to recreate it as shown. For you, just use the dataframe build code since you have *paragraphs* in your environment. For other readers of this answer, input data is here to check my solution (i.e., reproducible example).

Comment: Ok it worked, thank you very much, for real, you are god-sent. Thanks again A+++